# Need help using RF transceiver with RF amplifiers

Tags: amplifier, rf, impedance, waveguide

I'm trying to use the STM32WLE5C8 SoC that is both a microcontroller and an RF radio.

For my project I will be using the radio in the 800 - 900 MHz band (high-band configuration for this radio).

I need to be able to transfer data over an 8 km range. Since the high-output power mode of this radio is capped at 22 dBm (which is not quite enough for my purposes) I will be using an external RF amplifier IC in my design. To avoid amplifier saturation I think it's best to run the module in low-power output mode (15 dBm).

I want to be able to output at least 30 dBm @ 868 MHz.

From [this link](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stdes-wl5u2sbb.html#cad-resources) I acquired the reference schematic for a high-band, low-power design (CAD Resources > MB1791 Board schematics > MB1791-HighBand_LowPower-A01_Schematic.pdf).

The part of the schematic that includes the antenna connections is presented below.

[image]

If I want to connect an external amplifier in the TX path (including the RF switch), do I keep the circuit the same and just connect whatever the amplifier circuit would require between RF2 pin of the RF switch and where C19 and C22 meets? See below:

[image]

Or would the impedance matching circuit etc. before the RF switch need to change as well?

Is there a way I can simulate to know whether a radio would work with an amplifier using HFSS, CST, AWR, etc.?

One last note: Please don't flame at me for not specifying the data rate, antennas, etc. I just need to output 30 dBm @ 868 MHz using LoRa modulation for my project.

Comment: Why do you need that amplifier? Lora works without, and using that amplifier pushes this transmitter right into illegality. If you need your Lora system to be more robust, i.e., work over longer distances, you configure a higher SF and thus a longer transmission, yielding more energy per bit, instead of using an amplifier.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for the response, I know about the spreading factor however I  think to be able to send such a signal I would still need higher power. Increasing the spreading factor increases the bandwidth as well (as far as I know from the formula) to keep the same data rate. Don't I need more power to transmit a wider band?

Comment: No, it doesn't double the bandwidth, it doubles the length.

Comment: By length do you mean the duration of a symbol to represent a bit? Also according to this source https://www.rfwireless-world.com/calculators/LoRa-Data-Rate-Calculator.html  the bandwidth definitely increases to keep the same data rate when SF increases. If you check the formula when the coding rate and data rate are kept the same Bandwidth is relative to (2^SF)/SF. I agree that I should use a higher SF but I also think that I need more power nontheless.

Comment: @MarcusMüller One last thing to add: You people need to really relax about the legality issues. Although I agree that everyone should obey the guidelines of the EM spectrum usage you guys are taking it too far. I'm just doing this for a non-commercial, university student project. You react like its the end of the world for some reason every time someone tries to "break the laws of EM spectrum".

Comment: yes, but you don't need to keep the same data rate

Comment: and these are not guidelines, they are law, and as a communications engineer, my whole income for the next decades depends on people being smart enough to cooperatively use the spectrum instead of just deciding to use as much power as they like, which would lead to a breakdown in overall usefulness of the spectrum. So, it's really not us engineers who need to chill. This isn't hypothetical, either – spectrum regulations change over time, and bands in which low-regulation access doesn't work because too many users don't adhere to the rules, simply get reassigned to proprietary access.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you as always for your opinions. I am also studying the same engineering as you. I still think that a student project won't cause any harm to anyone. 

Also what do I do if my project is required to keep the same data rate? I don't want to trade my datarate for range. That's why I wanted to use an amplifier.

Comment: If you need more data rate than your method of communication over a given distance can offer you need a different method, not more power. Seriously, amplifying a low-power-oriented standard like Lora screams "wrong design choice". But I also don't see the use case where you need a fixed rate in Lora – it's never used in a constinuous stream, anyway, so data rate during transmission is practically a non-metric. For Lora, it makes more sense to talk about how many packets a day of how many bytes you want to send.

Comment: and very significantly, Lora networks suffer very quickly from congestion, since there's no coordinated spectrum access. You using more power than you're allowed affects potentially a lot of Lora devices as soon as the Lora-used band gets a bit more crowded. You're basically the same as someone throwing your trash in the river saying "I don't think *my* trash will lead to pollution". It *is* pollution.

Comment: I'm not going to be constantly transmitting data in a city or anything like that. This communication system with the amplifier is for a 6km altitude rocket. Just for a short time (duration of the rocket's flight) I want to be able to transmit the telemetry data.

Comment: but that sounds like you'll get great line of sight reception conditions. So, why the need for more power?

Comment: Because when we test the system we can't achieve a range further than 3-4km with 20 dBm @ 433 MHz. Now we are trying to switch to 868 MHz, and we want 8km+ range.

Comment: Then 8 dB more power won't do, anyways. First look how much further you get with higher SF and lower data rate, and if you can show you're getting closer to where need to be, use directive antennas on the ground